# Example of Open Source Backup Solution which uses Ahsay

Tags: backup, open-source

I'm working on a backup solution which uses a re-branded Ahsay software. Boss doesn't want me to reinvent the wheel and so I'm looking for an existing, open source solution that we can use to get ideas.

Does anybody know of a backup solution which uses Ahsay and is open source?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to backup (vm's)?, if they are not huge files you could use rsync